# Laravel whereIn with a where clause ErrorException in Grammar.php line 118:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Below is my laravel query:

```
$statusCondition = '[1]';

$users = DB::table('user_tracking')
                 ->join('user_detail', 'user_tracking.user_id', '=', 'user_detail.id')
                 ->select('user_tracking.*', 'user_detail.gender', 'user_detail.username', 'user_detail.auth_provider')
                 ->where('user_tracking.art_id','=','1')
                 ->where('user_tracking.visit_start_date','>',DB::raw('NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR'))
                 ->whereIn('user_tracking.status',$statusCondition)
                 ->get();
```

When I'm using whereIn then given below error can anyone help to resolved such issue:

```
ErrorException in Grammar.php line 118: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/sites/l/letsnurture.co.uk/public_html/demo/museum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 315 and defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$statusCondition` should be an array.

Replace

```
$statusCondition = '[1]';
```

with

```
$statusCondition = [1];
```